# Best way to iterate array in a random order, without changing the order of the original array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of M data items, and I'd like to update N of them.
I'd like it to be a random N out of the M that get their data updated. I'd like to retain the original array order, so not shuffling the original array.
What's the best was to do this?

I could do it like below, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it?

```
// example data:
$data = [
  ['h' => 5], 
  ['h' => 3], 
  ['h' => 15], 
  ['h' => 10], 
  ['h' => 0], 
  ['h' => 2], 
];

// array of M keys
$keys = array_keys($data);

// say I want to update 2 of them at random
$n = 2;

// randomise keys
shuffle($keys);

// and take the first N
$keys = array_slice($keys, 0, $n)

// then update those N items
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
  $data[$keys[$i]] = updateThisItem($data[$keys[$i]]);
}
```

Comment: I would have chosen a similar approach. Only the `array_slice` seems superfluous - your `for` loop does `$n` iterations only anyway, so whether there are more items in $keys or not, is irrelevant.

Comment: I think you already answered your own question! With @CBroe suggestion of ditching the unnecessary `array_slice()` So what do you believe is wrong with what you have coded

Comment: Yep, good point about the array slice.  I sometimes find people using array functions on here that I'd never fully understood before, so was just wondering if there was a way to reduce it down to some shorter functional implementation out of interest.

Comment: you can take a look at [array_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), it will save you a step, cf `$keys = array_rand($data, $n);`

Comment: @Kaddath I wondered about that - but will `array_rand` potentially repeat keys?  I know I didn't explicitly state that above, but I need each key to be used once only. --- I think from the wording it doesn't repeat keys - so this is another learning day!

Comment: it will not repeat keys in a single call, but I just saw that when `$n == 1` it doesn't return an array but the key itself, so if you plan that `$n` can be `1`, an extra test will be necessary